# resize a div using jquery.easyui.min.js

Tags: jquery

Re-size div in 1:1 ratio using jquery.easyui.min.js and bind risizable div within his parent div.

At this time resizable and dragable both are working but there is need to resize div in 1:1 ratio using this js

so Please place answer with jquery.easyui.min.js

Comment: Your question is not very clear, can you post some sample code and let us know where you are facing a problem?

Comment: Jqueryui code is at: https://code.google.com/p/jquery-easyui/source/browse/trunk/plugins/jquery.resizable.js?spec=svn611&r=603

And script at page is:
      <SCRIPT>
    $(function(){
 $('.content') 
  .resizable();
  
    });
    </SCRIPT>

Comment: please help any one

how i implement aspectRatio with  jquery.easyui.min.js